# Access is denied file upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, access-denied

I'm getting a access is denied when I try to upload a file to a directory with the ASP.NET Web API controller. When I upload a file on my Web Form, Default.aspx.cs, I have no access issue.

What would my default.aspx page have access, while my controller doesn't? Both files have the same "owner".

I've implemented impersonation, but that does not resolve the issue.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Comment: TBH, I don't know - I'm using Rackspace cloud site hosting.

Comment: do you have the permission to the path where you are uploading the file? I guess you are getting this error on production server, right?

Comment: Well, it *is* telling me access denied :) Again, I have no problem writing to the folder from my default.aspx page. It's just from the web api controller that it gives me this problem. And yes - on production server.